# How to prove this inequality with sum

Tags: number-theory

The inequallity is $$\sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-2\pi(a^2+b^2)}\leq \left(\sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-2\pi a^2}\right)^2 $$

I am not sure, but do I have to use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Rules of exponents , factor and change variables.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Much simpler. If you multiply out the square on RhS  you get LHS. So it is an equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LHS is nothing but $(\sum_{a\in\mathbb z} e^{-2\pi a^{2}})^{2}$ so equality holds.

We always have $(\sum_n a_n)^{2}=\sum_{n,m} a_na_m$ for any non-negative sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb  Z}$.

Comment: thanks for your help. I  only wondered why there is an inequality.